# Drop rows from dataframe, where every value from thirdcolumn onwards is 0

Tags: python, dataframe, row

I'm trying to remove rows where from the third column onwards the values are 0

I used the code below, which works, but I feel like there must be a far more effective manner to do this, here is my data frame: [image]

```
NRC_lexicon_wide = NRC_lexicon_wide[~((NRC_lexicon_wide['anger'] == 0) & (NRC_lexicon_wide['anticipation'] == 0) 
                                      & (NRC_lexicon_wide['disgust'] == 0) & (NRC_lexicon_wide['fear'] == 0) 
                                      & (NRC_lexicon_wide['negative'] == 0) & (NRC_lexicon_wide['positive'] == 0) 
                                      & (NRC_lexicon_wide['sadness'] == 0) & (NRC_lexicon_wide['surprise'] == 0)
                                      & (NRC_lexicon_wide['trust'] == 0))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, how about this:

```py
import pandas
import numpy


# Create a dataframe from a list of dicts will automatically find the column
df = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.DataFrame([{key: numpy.random.choice([0, 1, 2], p=[0.8, 0.15, 0.05]) for key in ["ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD", "ColE", "ColF"]} for _ in range(50)]))

# Start from this column onwards
start_column = 3

# Get a boolean value for each cell, indicating if the value is larger than 0
larger_than_zero = df.loc[:, df.columns[start_column:]] > 0

# Get the rows for which any value in a cell is larger than 0
any_cell_larger_than_zero = larger_than_zero.any(axis=1)

# Select only the rows that have cells larger than 0
df = df.loc[any_cell_larger_than_zero]

# Or in a single line:
df = df.loc[(df.loc[:, df.columns[3:]] > 0).any(axis=1)]
```